# Doubt about specific connectors

Tags: pcb, connector

I'm trying to find the name of the connectors I need to use in PCB to connect with the three cables below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I suspect the second one is a DIN5 connector and the third one is an IDC connector, but I don't have a guess about the first one.

Could someone help me?

Additional Info: The three cables are used in Quanser's 2DSFJ robot and these pictures are from the robot manual.

Update: The first cable connector is the "Output" connector of the picture below:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: well, your second and third picture already solved, I'd personally reduce your question to just one question. And then, I'd add info like where that connector is used – power for something? Microphone? Something else? Also, close-up pictures with measured dimensions would surely help.

Comment: It's a cable power for the DC Motor of Quanser's 2DSFJ robot. Unfortunately, I don't have the cable with me to get dimensions and they also don't appear in the manual. I have searched the entire robot manual and they just call this cable "Motor Cable" but don't say a thing about its specifications.

Comment: Without dimensions (and with such a dark picture), it's not really possible to tell on the first cable. It looks like a 4-conductor circular military connector, but without the pitch, there's no way to know the exact one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've updated my question with a new picture

Comment: @uint128_t I've updated my question with a new picture.

Comment: Ask Qanser? They seem to be in the business of selling robot controllers, so they actually are interested in helping their customers build systems that work more than they should be interested in selling cables. They know, and we don't.

Answer (score 1):

The first picture looks like it could be AMP (Tyco) CPC, or Circular Plastic Connectors.  These are fairly common.  Look at DigiKey or Mouser or a vendor like that.

A quick search for AMP CPC Connector yielded pictures that look very much like that.